# rails an array of many link_to links in a sentence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, collect

The problem is, some Organization(s) don't have addresses and it breaks the page (Couldn't find OrganizationUrl with id=1826_).  \

I'd like to somehow use the link if the address is present, and if not just show the name.

Any pointers?

```
@lot.organizations.collect{ |o| link_to(o.name, OrganizationUrl.find(o.org_id).address, :target => '_blank') }.to_sentence.html_safe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this (which is gross).

```
def link_to_many_organization(lot)
 @lot.organizations.map{ |o| 
  begin
    _url = OrganizationUrl.find_by_organization_id(o.org_id).address
  rescue
    o.name
  else
    link_to(o.name, _url, :target => '_blank')
  end
    }.to_sentence.html_safe
end
```

and the usage:

```
= link_to_many_organization(@lot)
```